# macOS resolution can't scale up

Tags: display, resolution, vmware, 4k

I'm running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 on VMware on Windows 10 Pro 1803 build 17134.1.

My screen's resolution is 3840x2160 (4K) and I want the macOS to be in resolution 3840x2009.
However. it seems impossible, due to a strange behavior in which when I go to System Preferences → Displays and either click "Default for display" or choose from the resolutions list "3840x2009" - the resolution is changed for like 1 second, and then returning to resolution 1920x1005.
**Note:** I just reinstalled VMware Tools.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try to reboot the VM?

Comment: You can try to set the resolution in "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist" on macOS and see.

Comment: @PratikaRana If you meant to edit [this](https://image.ibb.co/jBXRm7/Screen_Shot_2018_05_03_at_1_21_59_AM.png) file, then I don't know where to edit it.

Comment: Execute the following command in Terminal. "sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled". Then restart the VM. You should be able to get the required resolution.

Comment: It worked partly. If I don't resize the VMware window - it's okay. Otherwise, if I resize - the resolution scales down. Though if I do return the window to its previous size - it seems to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go Setting -> Display -> Display scaling and turn off check mark "Automatic adjust user interface size in the virtual machine". It works!